# How to compile or check syntax error in Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins

I have created a node.js application. I need to compile or do a check whether syntax error occurs before running the node.js service.I need to integrate this in jenkins. Kindly guide me to validate the node.js application

Answer (score 1):

Look into TypeScript. It is a language which allows you to get autocomplete with types and fails compilation if you have some syntax errors. It is a superset of JavaScript and transpiles to JavaScript.

Comment: The entire nodejs application need to be compiled before runing. Does grunt help?

Comment: If you use TypeScript you define a tsconfig.json file which defines what files you compile, the popular IDEs know how to work with it so you should have no problem. It's not a simple configuration though, probably you'll need to change all the app to TypeScript if you want to be sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js provides CLI option [`--check`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/cli.html#cli_c_check) or `-c` for checking a given file for syntax errors without running it. When working with Linux or MacOS a command like the following one helps with checking all obvious javascript files in a folder for containing basically working code:

```sh
find -name "*.js" | xargs node -c
```

Answer (score 1):

using `eslint` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint
It's a very common library to check the syntax of any JS/TS framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'node-syntax-error' module.
it helps you to detect and report syntax errors in source code strings.

When you type **node src.js** you get a friendly error report about exactly where the syntax error is. This module lets you check for syntax errors and report them in a similarly friendly format that wrapping a **try/catch around Function()** or **vm.runInNewContext()** doesn't get you.

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var check = require('syntax-error');

var file = __dirname + '/src.js';
var src = fs.readFileSync(file);

var err = check(src, file);
if (err) {
    console.error('ERROR DETECTED' + Array(62).join('!'));
    console.error(err);
    console.error(Array(76).join('-'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

> node --check

Only finds very grave errors and can be tricky to execute.

I would suggest to use a linter like 'eslint'. Because:

- It integrates easily with (npm lint or yarn lint)
- It catches almost all possible errors (way more than node -check)